# What are in-between foreground and middle ground and middle ground and background?

Tags: word-request

We have three terms for determining different level of depth in a movie shot and they are foreground, middle ground and background, but are there more words? How do you for example identify different depths within each of them, because, although very rare, we may sometimes see more level of depths than three, and sometimes in the middle ground alone we may see 2-3 levels of depths. I am sorry if I misused the term depth, but I guess most people will understand what I meant.

For example:

> In the foreground of the middle ground, we see a similar element that
>   is seen in the foreground of the background.

Comment: This seems like a rather technical question; you might consider asking on [Photography.se]. (Cross-posting is discouraged on the Stack Exchange, though, so if you decide that might be a better place to ask, you should delete your question here.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This is defintiely a question for https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are no in-between for foreground, middle ground and background, those three nouns are used in order to show spaces and depth.

[image]

There are only 3 zones:

[image]

However you can use the following terms:

> We can see the **Horizon line** between the mountain in the background
>   and the sky.
>
> As you can see, the **first mountain in the Middle Ground** is entirely
>   covered with trees

As well as: in the **[back/front]** of the **[foreground/middle ground/background]**.